# How do I select specific values from TypeScript / JavaScript String Literal Types against a single bitwise sum?

Tags: javascript, typescript

How do I select specific values from TypeScript / JavaScript String Literal Types against a single bitwise sum?
As a helper there can be a map of the Literal Types with bitwise keys: 1, 2, 4, 8, ...
I am not sure how to put the result / return value together so it returns the result compatible with the given type.

Variant 1:

```
  const result: "Aaa" | "Bbb" | "Ccc" | "Ddd" = selectByBitwiseSum1(5);

  // THE EXPECTED RESULT:
  result = "Aaa" | "Ccc";


  export function selectByBitwiseSum1(bitwiseSum: number): "Aaa" | "Bbb" | "Ccc" | "Ddd" {

    var result;

    var optMap = [ {key: 1, val: "Aaa"},
                   {key: 2, val: "Bbb"},
                   {key: 4, val: "Ccc"},
                   {key: 8, val: "Ddd"}  ];

    // THE DESIRED CONVERSION PLEASE  TO RETURN GIVEN TYPE (NOT STRING ARRAY)
    result = ???

                  // THE EXPECTED RESULT:
    //result = "Aaa" | "Ccc";

    return result;
    
  }
```

Variant 2 - array type:

```
  const result: ("Aaa" | "Bbb" | "Ccc" | "Ddd")[] = selectByBitwiseSum2(5);

  result = ("Aaa" | "Ccc")[];


  export function selectByBitwiseSum2(bitwiseSum: number): ("Aaa" | "Bbb" | "Ccc" | "Ddd")[] {

    var result;

    var optMap = [ {key: 1, val: "Aaa"},
                   {key: 2, val: "Bbb"},
                   {key: 4, val: "Ccc"},
                   {key: 8, val: "Ddd"}  ];


    // THE DESIRED CONVERSION PLEASE  TO RETURN GIVEN TYPE (NOT STRING ARRAY)
    result = ???
                  // THE EXPECTED RESULT:
    //result = ("Aaa" | "Ccc")[];

    return result;
    
  }
```

Comment: Why bitwise operand? Please provide a [example] using [StackSnippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the whole thing with this one-liner

```js
const arr="AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD,EEE,FFF".split(",");
console.log((5).toString(2).split("").reverse()
 .reduce((a,c,i)=>(!+c||a.push(arr[i]),a),[]).join(" | "))
```

`!+c||a.push(are[i],a` probably deserves a little explanation: `c` is a single digit ("0" or "1") of the binary representation of the number `5`, starting with the "least significant bit" (since I `.reverse()`d the array). The `+` in front of it converts the string into an integer and the negation  operator `!` turns it into `true` or `false`. The part after the following `||` operator will only be executed, if the first expression was `false`.

Comment: of course, but that doesn't answer the OP's question - the OP is clearly bit-shifting (bit masks) to find the string (why, I have no idea). In addition, the OP's unclear question addresses Typescript and typing, so it is unclear if the purpose is selecting the strings or selecting a type.

Comment: I like the bitwise trick, however, my main confusion is about the returned type of "AAA | CCC" - not a string array, which the JavaScript API I work with seam to want.

Comment: Well, the return string can easily be created by `.join()`ing the array before returning it, see my edited post.